# Counting a one to one function: Where does the + 1 come from in n-m + 1

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently reading up on counting one-to-one function and understood that when I want to count a set with m elements to a set with n elements, I can use the product rule to count the number of combinations such that

```
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*.......(n - m + 1)
```

I can see why there would be a n - m, but I can not seem to reason where the + 1 might come from. Any help would be beneficial, thanks!

Comment: It's actually n-(m-1).  In other words you start with (n-0) and you go to (n -(m-1)).  That's m terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because say for example n = 5 then

(5 - 1) = 4 and so 4 + 1 = 5

(5-2) = 3 and so 3 + 1 = 4

(5-3) = 2 and so 2 + 1 = 3

(5-4) = 1 and so 1+ 1 = 2

(5-5) = 0 and so 0 + 1 = 1

Therefore you need the plus one otherwise if you just had (n-m) the answer would always be one less than it is supposed to be and this is finding the factorial of n.

Comment: You could also think of it this way: To count from $1$ to a number $n$, we can label the first number $1$, the second $2$ and so on. Pretty soon, we realize we're just counting, so the answer is $n$. However, from $m$ to $n$, we can get $m$ to one by subtracting $m$ then adding $1$ to obtain the number of terms as $n-m+1$

Answer (score 0):

Say I have 3 objects and I enumerate them 1,2,3, then the number of objects I have is (3-1)+1. So in your case you have n-(n-m+1)+1=m objects.

Comment: I you have 5 objects, and you enumerate them 1,2,3,4,5, then you have (5-1)+1=5 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Let set $A$ has $m$ elements and set $B$ has $n$ elements.

Let denote the elements of $A$ as $a_0, a_1, \ldots , a_{m-1}$.

Let's assign values in the order from $a_0$ to $a_{m-1}$.

$a_0$ has $n-0$ choices.

$a_1$ has $n-1$ choices. (less one choices)

$a_2$ has $n-2$ choices.

We can see that $a_i$ has $n-i$ choices.

$a_{m-1}$ has $n-(m-1)$ choices.

Answer (score 0):

You need m factors. If you rewrite your product into

$(n-0)\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-3)...(n - (m - 1))$

You see that it is exactly what you need. The point is that you start form $0$, not from $1$